# Should I checkAndCallSafeTransfer while creating NFT?

Tags: erc-721, solidity

As per erc721 a good practice during transfer of an NFT is to use 'safeTransfer()' which calls:

> checkAndCallSafeTransfer

of the

> IERC721Receiver

interface.

My question is, when creating a new NFT I dont have any value for 'from' address because the contract is just generating a new token and assigning it to a new owner. Most other contracts I saw use '0x' for 'from' address during creation. My new asset creation would look something like below:

> 

```
MyAsset memory newAsset = MyAsset({
  ....// attributes
  });
uint256 assetId = xxxx;
require(_to != address(0), "Invalid address for transferFrom");
_assignAssetTo(_to, _assetId); //as per spec 
require(_checkAndCallSafeTransfer(_from, _to, _tokenId, _data));
```

The sample implementations by zepellin [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Holder.sol) for IERC721Receiver doesn't do much checking of addresses or anything. So if I do this check its fine. But what about the real world exchange implementations. Do they do the same? Because if any implementation does a check of 'from' not being '0x' my creation method would fail in case the asset is being moved to a contract and not a wallet.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Here is the relevant code: https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/blob/master/contracts/tokens/NFToken.sol#L360-L381

Comment: @WilliamEntriken Thanks for the pointer, I can see that code doesn't do any check for 'from' address before assignment. But my question was for method `checkAndCallSafeTransfer` of code implementing `IERC721Receiver` interface. I don't see either of that in the code you mention.

Comment: Thank you, now I am not sure I fully understand the question. But yes, there isn't any check of the `from` address.

Answer (score 3):

## Problem statement

We want to know if it is required and/or best practice to call `onERC721Received` on the receiving contract when creating ("minting") a new token.

## Literature review

The [ERC-721 standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) can tell us if this behavior is required. The relevant text is in the documentation for the `ERC721` interface:

```
/// @notice Transfers the ownership of an NFT from one address to another address
/// @dev Throws unless `msg.sender` is the current owner, an authorized
///  operator, or the approved address for this NFT. Throws if `_from` is
///  not the current owner. Throws if `_to` is the zero address. Throws if
///  `_tokenId` is not a valid NFT. When transfer is complete, this function
///  checks if `_to` is a smart contract (code size > 0). If so, it calls
///  `onERC721Received` on `_to` and throws if the return value is not
///  `bytes4(keccak256("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)"))`.
/// @param _from The current owner of the NFT
/// @param _to The new owner
/// @param _tokenId The NFT to transfer
/// @param data Additional data with no specified format, sent in call to `_to`
function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId, bytes data) external payable;
```

There is nothing in the standard which requires `onERC721Received` calls for minting operations. The standard is intentionally quiet on issues relating to creating or destroying tokens.

## In the wild

Perhaps Su Squares is the first standards-compliant ERC-721 product. Su Squares creates 10,000 tokens at contract deployment and then vends them for sale to customers. You *might* consider this similar to a minting process. Su Squares implement the vending process at https://github.com/su-squares/ethereum-contract/blob/master/contracts/SuVending.sol#L11-L24 which uses `_transfer`, the non-"safe" variant, at https://github.com/su-squares/ethereum-contract/blob/master/contracts/SuNFT.sol#L281-L329.

The last time I checked ("Validating NFT Authenticity". NIFTY Hong Kong. July 25,  2018), Codex Protocol was the second project that properly implemented ERC-721. They implement an internal `mint` function at https://github.com/codex-protocol/contract.codex-registry/blob/master/contracts/CodexRecordCore.sol. This also does *not* perform "safe" checking for the recipient.

These two implementations have not used the safe variant, of course you are welcome to do so or not as your application requires.

## What if I want to?

Here is an example implementation which inherits from [the reference implementation](https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721) and implements "safe" transfers for creating ("minting") new deeds.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

import "https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/src/contracts/tokens/nf-token.sol";

// Divides Earth's lat/long graticules up for claim. This DOES NOT INCLUDE
// ARTIC REGIONS!
contract AirDropEarthDeeds is NFToken {
    bytes4 internal constant MAGIC_ON_ERC721_RECEIVED = 0x150b7a02;

    // Claim ownership of an area ±0.5 deg N/S and ±0.5 deg W/E of a given
    // coordinate.
    function claimPlot(int256 latitude, uint256 longitude) external {
        require (latitude >= -66 && latitude <= 66);
        require (longitude >= 0 && longitude < 360);

        uint tokenId = uint(180 + latitude) * 10000 + longitude;
        address to = msg.sender;
        _mint(to, tokenId);

        if (to.isContract()) 
        {
            bytes4 retval = ERC721TokenReceiver(to).onERC721Received(msg.sender, address(0), tokenId, "");
            require(retval == MAGIC_ON_ERC721_RECEIVED);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the code references. As you mentioned correctly the "mint" method definition does not specify if you should call 'safeTransfer' or even 'Transfer'. So I had gone ahead and ignored the Transfer call during minting. Though in our contract we do not pre-mint. For now we are safely able to just assign the new asset to the buyer and thats it.